# How to get my webcam's RTSP/RTMP URL for streaming?

Tags: streaming, webcam, rtsp, live-streaming, wowza

I am new to media streaming, starting with Wowza. I want to test live streaming from my webcam (on my Dell Inspiron 1545 laptop) to other devices. This [tutorial](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?39) from Wowza tells me :

> enter your camera's RTSP URL and click Play

How/Where to get this URL ? Is it OS specific, or device specific ? Does a webcam by default provide a RTSP/RTMP stream, or I need to put some other code/application on my computer for this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Web camera is just a video capture device, applications can acquire video/images from. RTSP/RTMP URLs assume that video, typically in encoded format, can be obtained via network, using either of the two protocols.

So there is a missing step between webcam and availability of URLs: you need an application which captures video from the web camera, encodes it and makes it available on network.

Comment: can you please help me out with references for such application which captures video....Open Source please...

Comment: @Wazzzy did you get any application for that?